# Auto refresh numbers of user online by ip in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Please help,
I wanted in home page numbers of user online auto refresh.

script I'm using:

online.php

I'm Create in function:

```
function online_ip() {
```

This is the text you want to explain the number.

```
$explain = 'User Online: ';
$explain_ip = '<br />Your IP: ';
```

Add online numbers. You can set this to 0 for actual numbers

```
$additions = 0;
```

This is the refresh time in minutes.

```
$timer = 10;
```

Name of the file where all the data will be saved.

```
$filename = 'configs/online.lst';



if (!$datei) $datei = dirname(__FILE__)."/$filename";
$time = @time();
$space = " ";
$ip = get_client_ip();
$string = "$ip|$time\n";
$a = fopen("$filename", "a+");
fputs($a, $string);
fclose($a);



$timeout = time()-(60*$timer);

$all = "";
$i = 0;
$datei = file($filename);
for ($num = 0; $num < count($datei); $num++) {
    $pieces = explode("|",$datei[$num]);
    if ($pieces[1] > $timeout) {
        $all .= $pieces[0];
        $all .= ",";
    }
    $i++;
}

$all = substr($all,0,strlen($all)-1);
$arraypieces = explode(",",$all);
$useronline = count(array_flip(array_flip($arraypieces)));
```

display how many people where activ within $timeout

```
 echo $explain, $useronline+$additions, $explain_ip, $ip;
```

Delete

```
  $dell = "";
    for ($numm = 0; $numm < count($datei); $numm++) {
        $tiles = explode("|",$datei[$numm]);
        if ($tiles[1] > $timeout) {
            $dell .= "$tiles[0]|$tiles[1]";
        }
    }



 if (!$datei) $datei = dirname(__FILE__)."/$filename";
    $time = @time();
    $ip = get_client_ip();
    $string = "$dell";
    $a = fopen("$filename", "w+");
    fputs($a, $string);
    fclose($a);
```

end function:

```
}
```

in home_page.php

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I'm refress Javascript (not working)

```
setInterval(myOn, 1000);
function myOn() {
    <?php include('online.php'); ?>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<?php online_ip(); ?>"; 
};

setTimeout(myOn, 10000);
```

Thanks, @okolimar:

```
var myOnl = setInterval(myOn, 5000);
function myOn() {
$.get( "online.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#demo" ).html( data );
});
};
setTimeout(myOn, 5000);
```

Comment: The output from the PHP never change, even if your javascript function runs in an interval. If you want to fetch data from the server after the page has loaded, you'll have to use ajax.

Comment: Have you tried using **ajax**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function myOn needs to call with AJAX proper php file, that will contain information that you need. This is not working because the PHP part is executed only once when you show the page, see the source in the inspector. The `<?php online_ip(); ?>` is executed on the server and served in the js file.

To get the dynamics you need to call something like:

```js
$.get( "somefile.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#demo" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

in the somefile.php you need to have:

```
<?php 
   include('online.php'); 
   online_ip();
?>
```

Comment: thanks.  I removed the function in used only "online.php"